# How to convert image into binary format in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, binaryformatter

I am working on a project where I need to upload image to my server. I want to store my image's binary data to BLOB data type field in database. Therefore I need to convert my image into binary format. So that it can be saved on servers database.

So How to convert an image into binary format? Please advise.

Comment: Use the CoreGraphics' method UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage *image), which returns NSData and save it this way.

Comment: Thanks @BuntyMadan But it doesn't convert image in binary format.

Comment: But You can send the NSData raw data to the server and then convert it into UIImage.

Comment: What do you mean by `binary format`?

Comment: Yeah, define "binary format".  Everything on the phone is binary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `CoreGraphics`' method `UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage *image)`, which returns `NSData` and save it. 
and if you want to convert it into again `UIImage` create it using `[UIimage imageWithData:(NSData *data)]` method.

Demo to send your UIImage to Server

```
- (void)sendImageToServer {
       UIImage *yourImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
       NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
       NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [imageData length]];

       // Init the URLRequest
       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://yoururl.domain"]]];
       [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
       [request setHTTPBody:imageData];

       NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
       if (connection) {
       }
       [request release];
 }
```

Comment: May you provide a Swift example of just the first two lines (before code block)? I'm trying it and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
//OR
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

According to requirement.