# Convert Binary Image to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting binary image from web server , I need to covert it into UIImage and show it using QLPreviewController ,

Please help me.

Comment: Please have a look around SO for questions that already have answers before posting a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396797/how-to-convert-image-into-binary-format-in-ios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360986/reading-binary-image-data-from-a-web-service-into-uiimage

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to split in more questions.

Comment: so what you have tried for it ? show some code here.

Comment: Check 

[Base64 string into UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios/11251478#11251478)